# React Script Test not terminate after tests have been completed

Tags: github-actions, react-testing-library

I try to run npm test in Github Action, but it just stuck there forever. I can see that the tests are completed successfully in very short time, so I have no idea why it is not terminating

This is the test script in package.json

```
"test": "react-scripts test --watchAll --coverage --forceExit --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!axios)/\"",
```

Comment: when I try to run npm test locally, it will display the watch usage (ask user to press 'x' to do something for example press q to exit watch mode) is this causing this issue?

Comment: solve the issue by edit the script by adding watchAll=false

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to set the environment variable `CI` to `true` and remove `--watchAll` flag:

```json
"test": "CI=true react-scripts test"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `--watchAll` value to `false`. Also more details you can find here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#windows-cmdexe

Ex:
`react-scripts test a --coverage --watchAll=false`

PS: I'm using `"react-scripts": "5.0.1",`

Answer (score -1):

You can try removing the **--watchAll** flag from the test script to see if that helps. The script should then run the tests once and exit when they are completed.

It's possible that the **--watchAll** flag is causing the test script to stay running indefinitely.

Comment: I have try it, but it seems like it stuck at "No tests found related to files changed since last commit."

Comment: try to specify it with your test files location using something like this at the end: --testMatch='/tests//*.test.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'"

Comment: Removing of this flag did't work, by default it's  ```--watchAll=true``` i think that;s why.